# Is it possible to create image of sim card and use it on Android phone?

Tags: android, gsm

I have a android phone and want to have two sim cards active at a time. But my phone does not support dual sims.

I was wondering whether it is possible to create a program that will copy the sim card on phone memory and simulate to phone as if there is real sim card. In this way we can have virtually any number of sim cards plugged into any phone.

I have following queries before I start programming any of such thing

- Is this possible ?
- I googled about inner working on SIM card I found out that the communication between antenna and mobile happens using some serial number generated by SIM and this serial is matched with the signal from antenna. Anyone has good links to understand the working on SIM cards?
- Where do I start with? I have little understanding of GSM protocol. Do I need to know about GSM?

Answer (score 3):

SIM card cloning is technically possible, yet even if you manage to have your SIM card copied you will not be able to write a program to simulate SIM card, as SIM card is handled in hardware and your app will not have access to that hardware. Also it is not just a matter of having 2nd SIM. Dual phones require different hardware approach, different logic in the system logic and firmware etc, etc. So unfortunately "Look for real dual phone" is the much cheaper approach here.

Answer (score 2):

The SIM card reading and managing is not part of android software stack. This is part of Protocol stack which is run on a separate processor.

So this will not be possible. So even if you root a device to give android the SIM values, the Communication Processor that does protocol handling will not have updated values